# Revisions of a question

Tags: discussion, support, edit-history

I'd like to know how can one find the revisions of a question which has not been previously edited. (In the last case I know what I have to do: click on "Edited date...".)

Comment: Write the URL, `http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/<postID>/revisions`, in the address field of your browser. (That also works for `/timeline`, by the way).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. So, not an available button to click on it in this case :(

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Depending on the browser, one could make a user script or bookmarklet to add the button.

Comment: I don't understand. If it hasn't been edited, how can it have revisions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can still access the page that would show edits if they existed, and the URL still calls it "revisions" regardless. E.g., the "revisions" for this question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/25859/revisions This used to be useful for getting the source (to learn how to write math), but now anyone can get the source with edits or suggested edits.  Now the only use I can think of when there aren't edits is seeing bounty history.  Oh, getting source of locked posts is suggested here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135959/

Comment: You can also see deletion/undeletion, closing/reopening.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-history/info It works similarly for [timeline](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info). There is also this feature request on this meta: [Is there an easy way to access the revision list of an unedited question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6196) (And you can find several links to related posts on the main meta.)